# Array not properly populated with dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I've got a problem with populating an array with dates.

I'm trying to get last 12 months + the current month giving me a total of 13 months that I want to add to a select list.

Once the document is ready I'm populating the array with the dates.

I've tried populating the dates array directly in the PopulateDates() instead of the datesArray but that still gave the same effect when writing to console outside the function.

What am I missing here?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dates = new Array();
  dates = PopulateDates();

  for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    console.log("Date " + i + ": " + dates[i]);
    // This returns April 01 2020 for each field
  }
});

function PopulateDates() {
  var datesArray = new Array();

  var startDate = new Date();
  startDate.setUTCFullYear(startDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1, startDate.getUTCMonth(), 1);

  var dateIterator = startDate;

  for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    datesArray.push(dateIterator);
    console.log("Added: " + dateIterator);
    //This returns different dates correctly.
    //Starting from March 2019 to March 2020

    dateIterator.setMonth(dateIterator.getMonth() + 1);
  }

  return datesArray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would like the console.log("Date " + i + ": " + dates[i]); to display the same information as the one in the PopulateDates() - so all the months from March 2019 untill March 2020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because same object is being pushed into the array. Make a clone of the iterator and then push it into the array.

```
let clone = new Date(dateIterator.getTime());
datesArray.push(clone);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I thought that the setMonth() should be treated like a = a.setMonth(X) and would overwrite the current variable. Is that not correct then?

Comment: No. That just modifies the `month` value. The date object remains the same.

Comment: You can do `datesArray.push(new Date(dateIterator.setMonth(dateIterator.getMonth() + 1)))` to increment and copy the Date in one go. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

So the other answer fixed the reason you did not get different months. Is this what you were actually looking for?

```js
$(function() {
  const $sel = $("#months");
  let date = new Date();
  date.setUTCFullYear(date.getUTCFullYear() - 1, date.getUTCMonth(), 3); // normalise on 3rd of the month so all locales has the same month
  for (let i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
    const monthNum = date.getMonth() + 1;
    $sel.append(`<option value="${monthNum}">${date.getFullYear()} - ${month}</option>`)
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="months">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The previous answer covered what I was looking for. The select list is what I will tackle myself next and thank you for providing the answer. I will definitely use some of it.

Comment: The OP appears to be working in UTC, but `date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' })` and `const monthNum = date.getMonth()+1;` are working with local values. For those west of Greenwich, a date for say 2020-01-01 UTC will be 2019-12-31 local.

Comment: @RobG Oops. Any suggestions as to how to make sure that does not matter? I normally set the time to 15:00

Comment: I assume we can set it to the 3rd too

Comment: You can use `getUTC*` methods. Also, consider the *Intl* object formatting options, using `timeZone: 'UTC'` and [*formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts). :-)

Comment: @RobG what about the method I used now. Should work just fine no?

Comment: @mplungjan—yes, that works. The biggest timezone offset is +14, so 3 days is sufficient. But just using all local (non–UTC) methods seems simpler. :-)

Comment: @RobG thanks - I did not know or use the formatToParts - but your last statement confuses me - you approve of my local non-UTC method or you suggest OP to not use UTC methods?